# Dealing with Vectors - cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost

Tags: c++, vector, cuda

It is not obvious how to use std::vector in CUDA, so I have designed my own Vector class:

```
#ifndef VECTORHEADERDEF
#define VECTORHEADERDEF

#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

template <typename T>
class Vector
{
private:
   T* mData;   // data stored in vector
   int mSize;  // size of vector
public:
        Vector(const Vector& otherVector);  // Constructor
        Vector(int size);   // Constructor
        ~Vector();   // Desructor

        __host__ __device__ int GetSize() const; // get size of the vector

        T& operator[](int i);  // see element

        // change element i
        __host__ __device__ void set(size_t i, T value) {
                mData[i] = value;
        }

        template <class S>    // output vector
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, Vector<S>& v);
};


// Overridden copy constructor
// Allocates memory for new vector, and copies entries of other vector into it
template <typename T>
Vector<T>::Vector(const Vector& otherVector)
{
   mSize = otherVector.GetSize();
   mData = new T [mSize];
   for (int i=0; i<mSize; i++)
   {
      mData[i] = otherVector.mData[i];
   }
}   

// Constructor for vector of a given size
// Allocates memory, and initialises entries to zero
template <typename T>
Vector<T>::Vector(int size)
{
   assert(size > 0);
   mSize = size;
   mData = new T [mSize];
   for (int i=0; i<mSize; i++)
   {
      mData[i] = 0.0;
   }
}

// Overridden destructor to correctly free memory
template <typename T>
Vector<T>::~Vector()
{
   delete[] mData;
}

// Method to get the size of a vector
template <typename T>
__host__ __device__ int Vector<T>::GetSize() const
{
   return mSize;
}

// Overloading square brackets
// Note that this uses `zero-based' indexing, and a check on the validity of the index
template <typename T>
T& Vector<T>::operator[](int i)
{
        assert(i > -1);
        assert(i < mSize);
        return mData[i];
}

// Overloading the assignment operator
template <typename T>
Vector<T>& Vector<T>::operator=(const Vector& otherVector)
{
   assert(mSize == otherVector.mSize);
   for (int i=0; i<mSize; i++)
   {
      mData[i] = otherVector.mData[i];
   }
   return *this;
}

// Overloading the insertion << operator
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, Vector<T>& v) {
   for (int i=0; i<v.mSize; i++) {
      output << v[i] << "   ";
   }
  return output;
}
```

My main function - where I just pass a vector to the device, modify it and pass it back - is as follows (with the kernel designed just for testing purposes):

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Vector.hpp"


__global__ void alpha(Vector<int>* d_num)
{
        int myId = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;


        d_num->set(0,100);
        d_num->set(2,11);
}


int main()
{
        Vector<int> num(10);

        for (int i=0; i < num.GetSize(); ++i) num.set(i,i); // initialize elements to 0:9

        std::cout << "Size of vector: " << num.GetSize() << "\n";
        std::cout << num << "\n"; // print vector

        Vector<int>* d_num;

        // allocate global memory on the device
        cudaMalloc((void **) &d_num, num.GetSize()*sizeof(int));

        // copy data from host memory to the device memory
        cudaMemcpy(d_num, &num[0], num.GetSize()*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);


        // launch the kernel
        alpha<<<1,100>>>(d_num);


        // copy the modified array back to the host, overwriting the contents of h_arr
        cudaMemcpy(num, &d_num[0], num.GetSize()*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

        std::cout << num << "\n";


        // free GPU memory allocation and exit
        cudaFree(d_num);

        return 0;
}
```

The problem I encounter is with cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost. It does not really copy the device vector to the num vector as can be seen from the output.

How should I deal with that? (Please be explicit, I am fairly new to CUDA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will create a valid pointer to the first element of the vector `num`:

```
    cudaMemcpy(d_num, &num[0], num.GetSize()*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
                      ^^^^^^^
```

This will not:

```
    cudaMemcpy(num, &d_num[0], num.GetSize()*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
               ^^^
```

The name of a your `Vector` object is not a pointer to its first data element.  Instead, you should write that line in a similar fashion to the first one you wrote, like this:

```
    cudaMemcpy(&num[0], d_num, num.GetSize()*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

However this by itself is not a fix.  Note that `d_num` is not a `Vector`, but is already a pointer, so we can use it directly in these operations.  Although it is not wrong to use `&(d_num[0])`, it is unnecessary to do so.

Because `d_num` is not a `Vector` (as you have allocated it - it is a bare pointer to a set of `int` quantities), your usage of `Vector` methods in the kernel is also broken.  If you want to use `Vector` methods in the kernel, you will need to pass it an actual `Vector` object, not just the data.  Since passing an object will require device data handling within the object (data accessible on the host is not accessible on the device, and vice-versa), it is an extensive re-write of your `Vector` class.  I've made a limited attempt at that, showing one possible way forward.  The basic methodology (ie. one possible approach) is as follows:

1. The object will contain pointers to both a host copy of the data and a device copy of the data.
2. At object instantiation, we will allocate both, and initially set our "reference" pointer to point to the host copy.
3. Prior to usage on the device, we must copy the host data to the device data, and the `to_device()` method is used for this purpose.  This method also switches our "reference" pointer (`mData`) to refer to the device-side copy of the `Vector` data.
4. In addition to copying host data to device data "internal" to the object, we must make the object *itself* usable on the device.  For this, we copy the object itself via pointer to a device-side copy (`d_num`).
5. We can then use the object in the usual way on the device, for those methods which have a `__device__` decoration.
6. After completion of the kernel, we must update the host copy of the data and switch our "reference" pointer back to the host data.  the `to_host()` method is provided for this purpose.
7. Thereafter the object can be used again in host code, reflecting the data changes if any which occurred in the kernel.

Here is a worked example:

```
$ cat t101.cu
#include <iostream>

#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

template <typename T>
class Vector
{
private:
   T* mData, *hData, *dData;   // data stored in vector

   int mSize;  // size of vector
public:
        Vector(const Vector& otherVector);  // Constructor
        Vector(int size);   // Constructor
        ~Vector();   // Desructor

        __host__ __device__ int GetSize() const; // get size of the vector
        __host__ __device__ T& operator[](int i);  // see element

        // change element i
        __host__ __device__ void set(size_t i, T value) {
                mData[i] = value;
        };

        __host__ __device__ Vector<T>& operator=(const Vector<T>& otherVector);
        void to_device();
        void to_host();
        template <class S>    // output vector
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, Vector<S>& v);
};


// Overridden copy constructor
// Allocates memory for new vector, and copies entries of other vector into it
template <typename T>
Vector<T>::Vector(const Vector& otherVector)
{
   mSize = otherVector.GetSize();
   hData = new T [mSize];
   cudaMalloc(&dData, mSize*sizeof(T));
   mData = hData;
   for (int i=0; i<mSize; i++)
   {
      mData[i] = otherVector.mData[i];
   }
}

// Constructor for vector of a given size
// Allocates memory, and initialises entries to zero
template <typename T>
Vector<T>::Vector(int size)
{
   assert(size > 0);
   mSize = size;
   hData = new T [mSize];
   cudaMalloc(&dData, mSize*sizeof(T));
   mData = hData;
   for (int i=0; i<mSize; i++)
   {
      mData[i] = 0.0;
   }
}

// Overridden destructor to correctly free memory
template <typename T>
Vector<T>::~Vector()
{
   delete[] hData;
   if (dData) cudaFree(dData);
}

// Method to get the size of a vector
template <typename T>
__host__ __device__
int Vector<T>::GetSize() const
{
   return mSize;
}

// Overloading square brackets
// Note that this uses `zero-based' indexing, and a check on the validity of the index
template <typename T>
__host__ __device__
T& Vector<T>::operator[](int i)
{
        assert(i > -1);
        assert(i < mSize);
        return mData[i];
}

// Overloading the assignment operator
template <typename T>
__host__ __device__
Vector<T>& Vector<T>::operator=(const Vector<T>& otherVector)
{
   assert(mSize == otherVector.mSize);
   for (int i=0; i<mSize; i++)
   {
      mData[i] = otherVector.mData[i];
   }
   return *this;
}

// Overloading the insertion << operator
// not callable on the device!
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, Vector<T>& v) {
   for (int i=0; i<v.mSize; i++) {
      output << v[i] << "   ";
   }
  return output;
}

template <typename T>
void Vector<T>::to_device(){
  cudaMemcpy(dData, hData, mSize*sizeof(T), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  mData = dData;
}

template <typename T>
void Vector<T>::to_host(){
  cudaMemcpy(hData, dData, mSize*sizeof(T), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  mData = hData;
}

__global__ void alpha(Vector<int> *d_num)
{


        d_num->set(0,100);
        d_num->set(2,11);
        (*d_num)[1] = 50;
}


int main()
{
        Vector<int> num(10);

        for (int i=0; i < num.GetSize(); ++i) num.set(i,i); // initialize elements to 0:9

        std::cout << "Size of vector: " << num.GetSize() << "\n";
        std::cout << num << "\n"; // print vector

        Vector<int> *d_num;
        cudaMalloc(&d_num, sizeof(Vector<int>));

        num.to_device();
        cudaMemcpy(d_num, &(num), sizeof(Vector<int>), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        // launch the kernel
        alpha<<<1,1>>>(d_num);


        // copy the modified array back to the host, overwriting the contents of h_arr
        num.to_host();

        std::cout << num << "\n";


        // free GPU memory allocation and exit

        return 0;
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_61 -o t101 t101.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t101
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
Size of vector: 10
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
100   50   11   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Notes:

1. According to my testing, your posted code had various compile errors so I had to make other changes to your `Vector` class just to get it to compile.
2. Passing an object by value to the kernel will invoke the copy constructor, and subsequently the destructor, which makes things more difficult, therefore I have elected to pass the object via pointer (which is how you originally had it), to avoid this.
3. Your kernel call is launching 100 threads.  Since they are all doing precisely the same thing, without any read activity going on, there's nothing particularly wrong with this, but I have changed it to just a single thread.  It still demonstrates the same capability.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Robert. Your answer is very nice. The kernel was just experimental.
Do thrust vectors have a similar design?
Can I now declare (and pass to the device) a variable of type: Vector<Object>, where Object is a class which has as a private member another vector?

Comment: Thrust vectors do not have a similar design.  Thrust has a host vector and a separate device vector class.  They do not combine host and device storage into a single class.  However the design is (IMO) pretty clean and obviously a lot more fleshed out than what you have here.  To learn more about thrust vectors, try the thrust [quick start guide](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide).  Also thrust is open source.  Niether the method here nor the thrust (device) vector is  going to easily allow you to handle vectors of vectors, but vectors of simpler objects are possible.

Answer (score 1):

It is not just `cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost` part that you're having trouble with.

```
Vector<int> num(10);
Vector<int>* d_num;
cudaMalloc(&d_num, num.GetSize()*sizeof(int));
```

This will allocate 40 bytes on the cuda global memory(assuming `sizeof(int)` is 4), which is pointed by `d_num` of type `Vector<int>*`. I don't think you are expecting `Vector<int>` object itself to be 40 bytes.

Let's try another way.

```
cudaMalloc(&d_num, sizeof(Vector<int>));
cudaMalloc(&d_num->mData, num.GetSize()*sizeof(int)); // assume mData is a public attribute
```

Unfortunately, the second line will emit `segmentation fault` because you are accessing device memory from host code(`d_num->mData`).

So your implementation of Vector class has many fallacies. If you're planning to have a fixed size array, just declare d_num as a pointer.

```
int* d_num;
cudaMalloc(&d_num, num.GetSize()*sizeof(int));
cudaMemcpy(d_num, &num[0], num.GetSize()*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
// .. some kernel operations
cudaMemcpy(&num[0], d_num, num.GetSize()*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thrust is library written for CUDA and it has vectors. http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/
Maybe it has all the functions you need, so why reinvent the wheel if you dont have to.

Comment: Max, the reason is that, I will want to have a vector<type>, where type will also be an object containing vectors, and then I don't know how should I declare the vectors inside this object.. as host or device vectors?
In the end, this question may be viewed as a more general one.